# Beginning a paragraph with Also or Furthermore

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am writing a cover letter and I would like to know if I can begin a paragraph with either Also or furthermore . Why I am asking is because someone told me starting a sentence with "Also" is frowned upon but I want to get a second opinion on this .

Comment: Please share the paragraph you're considering (and the one that immediately precedes it).

Answer (score 5):

Beginning a paragraph with *Also* may give some editors heartburn because it indicates the context of the first sentence of that paragraph is tightly bound to the material it follows.  Consider moving that sentence to the preceding paragraph.

Comment: However, if there are (say) mulit-sentence paragraphs B and C both supporting multi-sentence paragraph A, then one might reasonably start B and C with "Also" and "Furthermore".

Comment: @AndrewLeach I personally agree with you. I only wanted to indicate why some might not.

Comment: It depends on the context where _also_ and _furthermore_ are being used. When used to support statements being made in preceding paragraph, the use of _also_ and _furthermore_ are perfectly valid English constructs. However, if the first paragraph makes a positive point about something, with subsequent paragraphs bringing out the negatives of it, usage of _also_ and _furthermore_ would be wrong then. A correct recommendation can therefore be made when OP provides the context.

Comment: Dr Gerard Sharpling at [Warwick University](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/al/learning_english/leap/grammar/discourse/) gives a reasoned discussion of discourse markers / sentence connectors, including a section on the linking of paragraphs. Gary and Andrew both wisely point out that discourse context governs what connectors (if any) it is advisable to use to bridge paragraphs.